# WkWebView selects text when interacting with "user-select: none" area

Tags: css, ios

In an iOS iPad app with a single fullscreen WKWebView, when long-pressing into an area with `user-select:none` on it, <s>random</s> the first text in the next best area without `user-select: none` is selected.

How can one prevent this behavior? I would expect that long-pressing in any area but `text` would just be ignored. Note that even the `body` has `user-select:none`, didn't help either.

Example content:

```html
<style>
  .with-select {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
  }
  .no-select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
</style>
<body class="no-select">
  <div id="nav" class="no-select">
    Here be the navigation, user's will long-press items here to open a context menu
  </div>
  <div id="text" class="with-select">
    Seemingly random text is selected in here, even when things in "nav" are long-pressed
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just an observation. On my iPad IOS 14 it doesn’t seem to be random text that is selected but the first text it finds that doesn’t have user-select none.

Comment: @AHaworth Right! It only looked random to me because the center area is dynamic and scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that on IOS the first word in the first text the browser finds that doesn't have user-select: none is selected.

This snippet puts a dummy 'word' after the nav div which it positions with CSS off screen. This stops the nav text being selectable.

However, this dummy word did become selectable by selecting the first word in #text and dragging back to the end of nav. The way round this seems to be to put dummy offscreen above everything (not to the left). Just to be sure if the 'word' does get picked up somehow it is made to be just a non breaking space (an ordinary space is not enough).

Experiments with trying to replace the dummy div with a pseudo element did not work, it was not picked up by itself but only alongside the first word of text.

So, this is not nice as it involves putting a seemingly spurious element between nav and text but I put it here in case it helps in a particular use case.

```css
.with-select {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.no-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.dummy {
  margin-top: -3000px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" class="no-select">
  Here be the navigation, user's will long-press items here to open a context menu
</div>
<div class="dummy with-select">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="text" class="with-select">
  Seemingly random text is selected in here, even when things in "nav" are long-pressed
</div>
```

Comment: The idea is great and the example works. Using keywords, one could intercept `onSelectionChange` events and un-select based on the range's text. Weirdly enough, the selection in my app still jumps into the center view despite having spread various dummy-select DIVs. Maybe it behaves differently in deeply nested structures.